# React/Redux fetching data and conditionally render a component - too many re-renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to fetch data from my backend, change the 'isLoggedIn' state accordingly and therefore render a component conditionally. I just can't get my around it on how to structure it in a way that the component does not render twice.

First in my AuthForm component, there is a login function. It sets a httpOnly cookie for refreshing the JWT token, and and a JWT token directly on the headers.

```
const login = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.post(props.baseUrl + "/auth/login", {
                email,
                password,
            })

            axios.defaults.headers.common[
                "Authorization"
            ] = `Bearer ${response.data.token}`

            dispatch(toggleLogin(true))
        } catch ({ response }) {
            console.log(response)
        }
    }
```

Since I want to display the Game UI instead of the AuthForm, I'm dispatching the toggleLogin action.

In the main component, i have a refreshToken function, that checks if the client got a httpOnly cookie and returns a new JWT if it is valid. So that the user is still logged in on a page refresh.

```
const Tamagotchi = () => {
    const isLoggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.isLoggedIn)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const refreshToken = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(baseUrl + "/auth/refresh-token")

            axios.defaults.headers.common[
                "Authorization"
            ] = `Bearer ${response.data.token}`

            dispatch(toggleLogin(true))

            setTimeout(() => {
                refreshToken()
            }, response.data.expiresIn * 1000 - 500)
        } catch ({ response }) {
            if (response.status !== 201) {
                dispatch(toggleLogin(false))
                console.log("Not authorized")
            }
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        refreshToken()
    })

    return (
        <TamagotchiWrapper>
            <TamagotchiView>
                {isLoggedIn ? <TamagotchiUI /> : <AuthForm />}
            </TamagotchiView>
        </TamagotchiWrapper>
    )
}
```

If the user is logging in, or is refreshing the page, the Tamagotchi component gets rendered twice. The state gets changed because `isLoggedIn` changes and therefore it renders again and calling the useEffect hook again.
How to go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the `refreshToken()` call inside of `useMemo` instead of `useEffect`. `useEffect` works after the component prints the JSX and useMemo works before it.

```
useMemo(() => {
  refreshToken()
}, []);
```

Comment: This way the ```refershToken()``` function doesn't get triggered when the user logs in, which I need it to trigger to refresh the token before it expires!

Answer (score 0):

Please provide empty dependency array which means only render during initial loading.

```
 useEffect(() => {
        refreshToken()
    }, [])
```

Comment: It gives me ESLint warnings to include ```refreshToken``` in the dependency array, which again results in the same behaviour. Also i tried to wrap the ```refreshToken()``` function inside a useCallback Hook, with ```dispatch``` as the dependency in it's array. This results in the function not getting triggered on login. It should tho, to refresh the JWT token once it expires.

Comment: Is it working, if you ignore the es lint warning? Else you can try making it a class component and call `refreshToken` in `componenetDidMount` life cycle method, but for that you need to use `connect` before export the component

Comment: It is working in a way. The Tamagotchi component only renders once, but i have difficulties calling the ```refreshToken()``` function on successful login.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to pass `refreshToken` as a dependency in `useEffect()` and wrap the `refreshToken()` function in a `useCallback` Hook.

Then pass the `refreshToken()` function to my AuthForm component and call it on successful login.

This way the `refreshToken` function gets called correctly when opening the app to authenticate the user, and on successful login to be able to refresh the token.

Comment: Can you please update answer with your code.

Comment: It tells me I have to wait at least 48 hours until i can mark my own answer as solution.
I will make a new answer tomorrow as i found a much cleaner solution and will mark it accordingly!